# SSIS Package Parameter assignment disappears when Adding Existing to another project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parameters, ssis, package

Visual Studio 2010 without SSDT or BIDS Helper
SQL Server 2012
We have a outside consultant developing some packages for us.  The packages need to be added to existing solutions that we have internally.  The package uses Package Parameters and when we "Add Existing Package" to the project, the parameter assignments disappear for parameter mapping in the data flow tasks.

I was recently brought in as a contractor and want to recommend they upgrade to at least VS2012 and install SSDT but I am not sure if this will fix the issue.  I have not seen this happen before but I jumped from 2008R2 straight to 2014.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Scott

---